# Can you connect a mamba405-mk2 flight controller with a FrSky R-XSR receiver?

Tags: flight-controller, frsky

Spec for mamba405: https://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/common-mamba405-mk2.html

Spec for R-XSR: https://www.frsky-rc.com/wp-content/uploads/Downloads/Manual/R-XSR/R-XSR%20ACCST%20-Manual.pdf

Looking at the two specifications the R-XSR requires both a SBUS In and Out however the mamba405 only has one SBUS connection. Moreover, the mamba405 spec says it only supports "unidirectional protocols", does this mean I can just connect the SBUS out?

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSSI = Received Signal Strength Indicator

The S(Smart) Port connects to the RSSI Pin on the flight controller for the telemetry information.

Only the SBUS out is necessary for most Kwads.

[image: Circuit]